# EMG design help using AD8221 INAMP

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, voltage-reference, biopotential

I'm designing active electrodes for surface EMG, active electrodes being electrodes directly connected to a pre-amp and filtering stage on the measurement site.
Im working with the AD8221 IN-AMP to pick up the differential signal and I am trying to eliminate the need for a reference electrode by driving the reference pin of the IN-AMP via a voltage divider and buffer to bring the AD8221 to midsupply level. 
However with my simulations I have failed to receive the desired midsupply voltage level at the reference pin and infact only get a few hundred millivolts. Can someone please explain to me the theory of operation with the reference pin? and whether this method will effectively eliminate the need for the reference electrode?

Circuit specs;
+/- 5V power supply for the entire circuit.
Gain = 100. (Rg = 499 Ohms)

I have read through the other threads related to my topic, but none have encountered the problem I have. I am running a simulation on MultiSim v.13

Update:  the current schematic

[image]

Comment: Even using this method, done with a proper low impedance vref, you will probably still need a reference electrode to keep down common mode noise

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply. Your help is much appreciated. Could you please tell me how the reference electrode would help keep the common noise down? I was hoping to use a tri-polar arrangement, so 3 electrodes, and then double differencing. Wouldnt that significantly reduce common noise?

Comment: Three electrodes are fine, two (which I thought you were trying) are not

Comment: Scot, thanks. May I also ask if it is possible to use the same reference common to 3 inamps?

Comment: Sure.  Just make sure it's low impedance.  I just used amN LM285-2.5 for an ad623 and 3 op amps, no prob

Comment: Okay. I will change the impedance. Should the voltage to the reference circuit (opamp and potential divider) be isolated from the rest of the IC's? I am planning on using a single battery to power all the IC's. It seems to be affecting my simulations.

Comment: No need to isolate it

Comment: In the design I am basing my design on, the same reference voltage is input to the input signal via resistors. In the different threads and else where, I have not seen this done, is this an allowable setup? I presume it is affecting my CMRR.

Comment: You should switch to a rail to rail input inamp

Answer (score 1):

The reference pin has a 20k ohm input impedance and your potential divider may be formed from large resistors i.e. values in excess of 10k - this will cause a problem. Try driving the ref pin with a voltage source. Also note that there is a leakage current from this pin of about 50uA. This will produce a 0.5 volt error when fed from a voltage source with a 10k impedance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I shall try what you have suggested and update. I was using 100k resistors.

Comment: May I also ask, is it possible for this same reference to be common for 3 INAMP's? I am trying to use the double differential method to eliminate Common mode noise.

Comment: You can use the same reference (low impedance output) for multiple AD8221s

Answer (score 1):

Looking in detail, now, the ad8221 will not work single sided.   If you are planning on rail spliting, this might be Ok, but be careful of your common mode input range.  You can use the ad623 single supply.  The gain of 100 is probably way too high.  You should assume there can be 150 mvolts of difference just because of electrode junction potentials, and you'll saturate without a big supply range, especially if working single sided.  Recommend modest gain, like 5 or so, then high pass and low pass filtering, then an op amp gain stage.  Overall gain of 500 may be more comfortable than 100.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Okay, I am planning on using a DC-converter (TC7660) to pump a negative supply for the chips. I am using Sallen-key 2nd order filters (high pass and low pass) pass band = 20-500Hz. I am however having problems simulating the power supply for the amplifiers, I am connecting a DC source across the power inputs of the amps.
I shall reduce the gain and update.
Many thanks Scott!

Comment: @RKTim  you might peek at the ad623 or ad8237.  Your design gets a whole bunch easier while remaining robust

Comment: Reading the data sheet for the AD8237, it seems like a much better choice.

Comment: Ad627 is another

Comment: I have changed to the AD8237 and set up like below,

Comment: Hello again, I switched my setup to use the 8237, last night it worked well, but now I am running it again just to test it and now I am getting the wrong results. Nothing has changed since then. Is there a way I can forward my schematic design to you for some sort of guidance?

Comment: If you can get a screenshot of your schematic to some image sharing site, I can insert it into your question if you don't have the privilege to add an image yet.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the timely reply yesterday, unfortunately I wasnt able to read your message yesterday otherwise would have responded. Yes, I am able to take screenshots and upload to an image sharer online, How do we do this?

Comment: @rktim, just post the link as a comment

Comment: Hi Scott, yet again, sorry for the delayed response. I have uploaded a file with my schematic of my Input-amplifier stage at (http://postimg.org/image/dlgaofdjz/) or (http://s27.postimg.org/w10rltroj/Amp_stage.png). have a look and let me know your thoughts please. Thanks a lot in advance.
Sequentially, could you please suggest a method of calculating my CMRR from my simulations?

Comment: @RKTim, I added the image to your question.  I try to peek at it tomorrow

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks a lot for uploading my schematic, Im sure it will help. I think I got it to work fine eventually, but now in my effort to push it and test the circuit, I introduced an offset voltage to my signal generator in the order of mV and this affects my signal significantly when my input voltage is in the uV. All I get out on the output is a flat line at the ref voltage. Any ideas why?